# Switch between Keyboards

Tags: keyboard, compiz, configuration, kvm-switch

I have two text entry resources: English & Persian. I had defined Alt+L Shft to switch between them. Then I installed "Unity Tweak Tool" and "CompizConfig Settings Manager". After the very first run of these two, Alt+L Shft don't change keyboard & I have to do it via clicking on language bar. I cannot find any specific configuration about keyboard in these two either. Should I uninstall them, or there is another way?
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was because of using CompizConfig Setting Manager on Unity, while having Gnome too. When I did a fresh installation and didn't use CompizConfig Alt+Shift worked perfectly. I think installing Gnome on Ubuntu creates errors too. If you want Gnome, just install Gnome Ubuntu; don't install Gnome on Unity Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The default key combination for switching between keyboards in Ubuntu is Alt + Shift. Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes. As I said, After Installing those two, Alt+Shift doesn't work & I have to do it by clicking.

Comment: Oh i'm sorry, I misread what you wrote. I thought it said Alt + L + Shift. My bad.

Comment: Thank You. Actually that L stands for Left. I should have explained better. Sorry.